# Error C2365: redefinition of enum and Error 2086 redefinition

Tags: c, enums, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a program that compresses and decompresses files. I want to make an enum like this for the type of operation: `typedef enum { COMPRESS, DECOMPRESS } operation;`.
Problem is, I get 4 errors:

```
Error   1   error C2365: 'COMPRESS' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
Error   2   error C2086: 'COMPRESS' : redefinition
Error   3   error C2365: 'DECOMPRESS' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
Error   4   error C2086: 'DECOMPRESS' : redefinition
```

I don't get what's wrong because I made an enum just like that for boolean values, and it works fine: `typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } boolean;`.

EDIT:
I was requested to add the entire .h file the typedef is in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum { COMPRESS, DECOMPRESS } operation;
void compress(FILE * file);
void compressArchive(FILE * files[]);
void decompress(FILE * file);
void decompressArchive(FILE * files[]);
```

and as n.m. said I do `#include "huffman.h"` in another file, `general.h` (that needs the `operation` type) and in `huffman.c`, and in `main.c`.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the tokens `COMPRESS` and `DECOMPRESS` are used in another enum named `enumerator`.

Comment: @RSahu I changed it to some gibberish just to check, but it still doesn't work, same problem (CMPR, DCMPR).

Comment: My magic crystal says you have an include file without include guards.

Comment: @n.m. I read on the wiki what are include guards, seems to be my problem. But I don't get how do I implement them. Help please?

Comment: Is your enum in a .h file (or a .c file)?  If in a .h file, can you edit the question, adding the entire .h file?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Edited as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the .h file in the question is called 'huffman.h', change it to the following:

```
#ifndef __huffman_h__
 #define __huffman_h__


#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum { COMPRESS, DECOMPRESS } operation;
void compress(FILE * file);
void compressArchive(FILE * files[]);
void decompress(FILE * file);
void decompressArchive(FILE * files[]);

#endif /* __huffman_h_ */
```

Comment: You put the #include <stdio.h> even though it already has include guards. So I guess it doesn't matter. Thanks.

Comment: #ifndef __huffman_h__, otherwise your include will never be processed.

Comment: @Pietro, Big bad on my part.  Thanks!